# Count number of columns from specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering how I can count the number of columns with data, but start the count from a specific column.

So here is a snippet of my worksheet -
[image: This shows all months of the year but I'm showing just showing January as its far too big to include all]

Either way id like to be able to all columns from column E to the last day of that row before the column break.

Currently I have this code -

```
With Sheets("Log")

For ClmnCount = 2 To 3
DateRange = Cells(ClmnCount, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Next ClmnCount

End With

End Sub
```

But for some reason DateRange when ClmnCount is 2 returns 13? I can't set a non variable range because I want the code to count every column as it loops down the rows. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Cells(ClmnCount & Columns.Count)` - change the `&` to a `,` perhaps.

Comment: No change if that is changed, I have amended the above though. I know that the above code won't exactly return what I want... but why 13? Reasonably I would have expected an output of either 3 or 38, but I'm not sure why 13.

Comment: Put a `.` in front of `Cells` and `Columns` too so that they actually refer to `With Sheets("Log")`

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh.... right Cells without . directs it to active sheet not with sheet. Shucks.. thanks